# Unable to find only Button Component for test

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have the following component and trying to perform tests on it.

I am able to find all other Components such as **Element** and **Table**.

But there is no result for finding **Button** object even though there are 2 of those.

Why is that the case?

To note Button, Element and Table component here are all custom components of mine.

Component being tested

```
export const MyComponent = () => (
  <div>
    <div style={{ margin: 20 }}>
      <Button onClick={() => {}}>
        Click Me!
      </Button>
      <Button onClick={() => {}}>
        Click Me!
      </Button>
    </div>

    <Element name="name">
      title
    </Element>
    <div>
      <Table name="name" />
    </div>
  </div>
);

export default MyComponent;
```

My test

```
describe('test page', () => {

     it('should click', () => {

    const mockSelectorToggle = jest.fn();
    const defaultProps = {};
    const initialise = props => shallow(<MyComponent {...defaultProps} {...props} />);
    const wrapper = initialise();

    // all the following found
    wrapper.find('div')
    wrapper.find('div').find('div')
    wrapper.find('Element')
    wrapper.find('Table')

    // nothing found. Why only Button not findable?
    // wrapper.find('Button')
    // wrapper.find('div').find('div').find('Button')

    // looking to test it this way
    wrapper.find('Button').first().simulate('click');
    expect(mockSelectorToggle).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

Comment: Hello! sorry the code you wrote is not well formatted, for example the `<Button Click Me!`, as it is, gives a compilation error. Also the code about `wrapper` refers to the variable before its declaration. Can you provide the correct code?

Comment: @EmanueleScarabattoli Sorry, updated.

Comment: Don't worry :) `shallow` is from `Enzyme` right?

Comment: @EmanueleScarabattoli Yes is from enzyme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well according to the `Enzyme` documentation, there are various selectors available, in particular, this

https://enzymejs.github.io/enzyme/docs/api/selector.html#1-a-valid-css-selector

and this

https://enzymejs.github.io/enzyme/docs/api/selector.html#2-a-react-component-constructor

Now the issue seems to be related to what explained here:

> React component name and props (Button, Button[type="submit"], etc) - however, please note that it is strongly encouraged to find by component constructor/function and not by display name.

My impression is that the selector is searching for the HTML `button` tag and not for your actual `Button` component.

My suggestion is to change your code in this way:

```
wrapper.find(Button);
```

So basically do what the documentation recommend: "find by component constructor/function and not by display name".

An interesting point:

https://www.w3.org/International/tests/html-css/selectors-case/results-selectors-case#elemattrname

> All user agents treated the HTML element and attribute names tested as case-insensitive.

Even if seems strange that the `Table` was found.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it. Bit weird cos as you said Table itself is a html element name too yet no issue with that. Also when I use the Button component, it says not found even though I have definitely imported it. While fiddling around, noticed mount was able to find it while shallow can't. Don't really have an explanation why.. but plan to go with mount.

Comment: I also had some issues with `shallow` against `mount` in some cases. The best idea is: "Try to understand why", the actual behavior is: "OK man! Does not work with shallow, let use mount!" ahahahaha obviously I am joking but it happens sometime :)